# Sort users in get_users() in custom order

Tags: sort, include, users

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users('include=5,6,2,7,12,8');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
...         
}
?>
```

Right now, these users will sorted by first name.

How do I sort this in the order the numbers are in `include=...`?

Example:

User 5 first, user 6 second, user 2 third etc.

Comment: Mabye [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167091/how-to-order-wp-user-query-results-to-match-the-order-of-an-array-of-user-ids/167095#167095) can help?

Comment: @birgire I though of that answer, just couldn't figure out where and who posted it ;-).

Comment: @PieterGoosen It's great to see so many different solutions for the OP ;-) But your solution (+1) addresses this question directly, whereas the one I linked to, does so only indirectly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler, faster method than the one by @Warface. This is an extention to @SyHolloway

The concept here is to wrap [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) in a new function in which you can sort the result from `get_users()` by the `include` parameter using `usort` and then return the resulted array sorted by `include`

This function does not make provision for the `fields` argument to be used when the `include` parameter has been set. `all` is the only value that will work. You can extent the function to make it work with the other values of the `fields` parameter when `include` is in use. Otherwise, if `include` is not set, the `fields` parameter works as normal.

Naturally, `orderby` and `order` will not work when `include` is used

This new function operates and is used in exactly the same way as `get_users()`, except for the above mentioned rules

Here is the function

```
function get_users_by_include( $args = array() ) {
    $blogusers = get_users( $args );

    if( isset( $args['include'] ) ){
        $include = $args['include'];
        usort($blogusers, function ($a, $b) use( $include ){
            $q = array_flip( $include ); 
            return $q[$a->ID] - $q[$b->ID];
        });
    }

    return $blogusers;
}
```

You can now use this in your template as follows

```
$users = get_users_by_include(array( 'include' => array(2,5,1,10,45,32,66) ) );
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo $user->ID . '</br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress returns an array of objects.
Have you tried using 'orderby' as an extra paramiter? eg

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users('include=5,6,2,7,12,8&orderby=id');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    //This will loop in the order of id 2,5,6,7,12  
}
?>
```

Now you know what ID's are in what order, you can use some php array sorting functions

- [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)
- [`asort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)
- [`ksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Also some more at [php maunual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Its not a total solution but should put you well on your way.

Comment: The OP want it ordered by the `include` array and not the `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Since WP doesn't respect the array order injected in the `include` array, I've made a little script to achieve it.

```
$user_id = array(2,5,1,10,45,32,66);

foreach($user_id as $uid):
    $user_query = get_users(array('role'=>'member', 'number' => 1,'include' => $uid));
    echo $user_query[0]->ID // or display_name like you like...
endforeach;
```

I know it's kinda lame to query each time the database but hey it works.

Comment: This will work, but you are hitting the db a lot. I still think that you should try to use some form of php sorting on the returned array

Comment: Yeah but sorting the array don't do anything in the `get_users()` include parameter. It will order it alphabetically or by IDs. To keep the array order injected, I can't think of any other ways.

Comment: Please see my answer. As I said, you need to make use of php sorting on the returned array from `get_users()`

Comment: Or you can have a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167095/31545) by @birgire.